# Redux-Forms onChange weird behaviour when using Dropzone

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to wrap my head around getting `react-dropzone` to work with `redux-forms`

```
export class AdminDropzone extends React.Component<any, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Field name='filesForUpload' component={renderDropzoneInput}/>
    );
  };
}

const renderDropzoneInput = (field: any) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropzone 
                name={field.name} 
                onDrop={(filesToUpload: any) => {
                    console.log(filesToUpload[0].preview);
                    return field.input.onChange(filesToUpload)
                }
            }>
                <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above triggers an `onChange` which causes `@@redux-form/CHANGE` to dispatch but for some reason the payload there simple has a single value and not the object I was expecting (containing all of the information of the file).

The `console.log(filesToUpload[0].preview)` outputs the preview property correctly.

A `console.log(filesToUpload[0].name)` also outputs the name correctly but the dispatch looks like below:

```
type: "@@redux-forms/CHANGE",
payload:
    0:
        preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/47c5ccef-8f78-408f-a376-528c0fc7e2da"
```

I am expecting to see the whole value of the file object (which contains name, size, last modified, preview, type etc). So where have they gone?

Any Ideas?